# linux kernel check if process is still running

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, pid

I'm working in kernel space and I want to find out when an application has stopped or crashed.
When I receive an ioctl call, I can get the struct task_struct where I have a lot of information regarding the process of the application.
My problem is that I want to periodically check if the process is still alive or better yet, to have some asynchronous call when the process is killed.

My test environment was on QEMU and after a while in the application I've run a system("kill -9 *pid*").  Meanwhile in the kernel I've had a periodical check on task_struct with:
volatile long state;    /* -1 unrunnable, 0 runnable, >0 stopped */
static inline int pid_alive(struct task_struct *p)

The problem is that my task_struct pointer seems to be unmodified. Normally I would say that each process has a task_struct and of course it is corespondent with the process state. Otherwise I don't see the point of "volatile long state"

What am I missing? Is it that I'm testing on QEMU, it is that I've tested checking the task_struct in a while(1) with an msleep of 100? Any help would be appreciated.

I would be partially happy if I could receive the pid of the application when the app is closing the file descriptor of the module ("/dev/driver").

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hive off the `task_struct` pointer and refer to it later.  If the process has been killed, the pointer is no longer valid - that `task_struct` is *gone*.  You also should not be using PID values within the kernel to refer to processes.  PID values are re-used, so you might not even be talking about the same process.

Your driver can supply a `.release` callback, which will be called when your driver file is closed, including if the process is terminated or killed.  You can access `current` from this callback.  Note that if a process opens your file and then forks, the process calling `.release` could well be different from the process that called `.open`.  Your driver must be able to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I mucked around inside the kernel. It seems to me if your process actually *dies*, then your best bet would be to put hooks into the code that tears down processes. If it doesn't die but gets caught in a non-responsive loop, you'd probably be better off causing an application level core dump.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked beautifully in my operating systems homework is to use a kprobe to detect when `do_exit` is called. What's beautiful is that `do_exit` will always be called, no matter how the process is closed. I think even in the case of a kernel oops this one will still be called.

You should also hook into `_do_fork`, just in case.

Oh, and look at the `.release` callback mentioned in the other answer (do note that `dup2` and `fork` will cause unexpected behavior -- you will only be notified when the last of the copies created by these two is closed).